# Using PlotLabel with ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I cannot get the label to appear on this vertical line!
(Mma 9.0.1 OS 10.8)

```
ParametricPlot[{.5, t}, {t, 0, .5}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLabel -> "z"]
```

Comment: Works fine on MMA 10.2, MBP OS 10.10.5. What version are you using?

Comment: Version 9.0.1.0 OS 10.8.5

Comment: Also works fine on MMA 9.0.1, MBP OS 10.10.5. Apparently the problem is with OS 10.8.5

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Can you perhaps include a screen shot of what you see (or don't see) and mark where you expect to see a label?

Comment: Are you looking for [labeling curve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=labeling+curve)?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear, so far, but I assume you mean the [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) and not [`PlotLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabel.html).

### Mathematica 10

```
ParametricPlot[
 {.5, t}
 , {t, 0, .5}
 , PlotStyle -> Blue
 , PlotLabel -> "here the plot Label"
 , PlotLegends -> {"here your legend"}
 , FrameLabel -> {"botoom", "left", "top", "right"}
 , PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### Mathematica 9

```
ParametricPlot[
 {.5, t}
 , {t, 0, .5}
 , PlotStyle -> Blue
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotLabel -> "here the plot Label"
 , PlotLegends -> {"here your legend"}
 , FrameLabel -> {"botoom", "left", "top", "right"}
 ]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

(Stumbled upon this question while looking for something similar. I'm not sure if a more elegant way to add labels to ParametricPlot exists, but this is what I've decided to go with...)

Assuming you *did* mean "PlotLabel" and not "PlotLegends", you can add the label manually.

```
Show[{
  ParametricPlot[{.5, t}, {t, 0, .5}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 0.6}}], 
  Graphics[Text["z", {1/2, 0.55}]]
  }]
```

That would give the following plot:

[image]